# Examples of Fourier Analysis in statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, fourier-transform

My brother in law is studying Electrical Engineering (undergrad level.) I was helping him select some coursework, and noticed that "engineering analysis" includes Fourier analysis. I didn't have exposure to this framework in any of my stats coursework. Is Fourier analysis used in some branches of stats? (Could you give some examples of where it's well situated.)

Comment: Here's a search to get you started: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=fourier+score%3A3+answers%3A1

Comment: Hi: On area where it is related is  statistical time series analysis. For example,  if you believe that there are hidden periodicities in a time series, the FFT might be useful. Also, the spectrum tells you at what frequencies there is greater energy in the series. ( but there are difficulties in estimating it ).  I don't know of a stat rs book that focuse ons fourier transforms  ( Note that there are actually four kinds. DTFT, FT, FS, and DFT ) but there are many dsp books that go into it in depth. Also, the people on dsp.stackexchange.com will help if you have more questions.

Comment: Also search for "convolution" and "convolve," because these (fundamental, widespread) operations are most efficiently implemented using Fourier transforms.  Also search "FFT," the standard abbreviation of "Fast Fourier Transform."  The first few chapters of a well-known stats textbook, Kendall & Stuart, focus on the theory of the FT because it interchanges distribution functions and *characteristic functions* (also a great search phrase).  The latter are a basic tool for analyzing probability distributions.

Comment: In time series analysis, beside  the *time domain* one finds  the *frequency domain* relying on Fourier analysis. I would recommend here the books by Athanasios Papoulis, These are ideally suited for people interested in  electrical engineering and cover a large number of topics probability and statistics: Markov chains, information theory, linear filtering, ... Also worth mentionning is the classical book by Priestley *Spectral Analysis and Time Series*.